# Bus 42 in Paris

Tags: public-transport, paris, sightseeing

I reserved in Grand Hotel Leveque and I want to take the bus 42 to have a tour in Paris. from which station should I start if I want to see all the city as much as possible and how can I reach this station?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to take bus 42? It does go through a few interesting places, but by far not that many, and it's not coming particularly close to your hotel either. How much time do you have? You'd probably be better off with one of the hop-on hop-off tourist bus tours. Are there specific attractions you would be interested in seeing/visiting?

Comment: Also note that the Paris bus network has seen extensive changes a few months ago, so the route of bus 42 has changed like many others.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [stop](https://www.ratp.fr/plans-lignes/busratp/42) on Avenue Joseph Bouvard just west of Avenue de la Bourdonnais.  which is 10 minutes walk from your hotel.

The name of the stop is "Rapp-la Bourdonnais".

But, IMO, it's not an efficient way to see the sights; plain city buses are not made to make it easy to see the sights (smaller windows, lower, full of regular people).

jcaron, in the comments suggested using the hop-on hop-off tourist bus; which would be easier and more practical.

Anecdotal, as someone who've been to Paris lot of time, it is sometimes fun just relax and take a regular bus and just do people watch.